# multiple main declaration in qtcreator project which uses googletest

Tags: mingw, qt-creator, googletest

I've added googletest project to build config(.pro file):

```
INCLUDEPATH += googletest-dir/googletest
INCLUDEPATH += googletest-dir/googlemock
INCLUDEPATH += googletest-dir/googletest/include
INCLUDEPATH += googletest-dir/googlemock/include

LIBS += -lgtest -Lgoogletest-dir/build/googlemock/gtest
LIBS += -lgmock -Lgoogletest-dir/build/googlemock

SOURCES +=\
...
src/EntryPoint.cpp \
test/unit/UnitTest1.cpp
```

where both cpp files contains main functions:
one for code and other for tests:

EntryPoint.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int returnValue = ERROR_CODE_OK;
...
    pGui->init(argc, argv);
    return returnValue;
}
```

UnitTest1.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
  //::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

How to tell project(how to configure qtcreator .pro file) that when i'm making release(make Makefile.release release) i don't need to use 2 main files in build but only EntryPoint.cpp one? And I still need second main for testing purpose in IDE.

Comment: This is not how you use goggletest. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/31324930/1362568 and answer.

Comment: I think this is a good decision but it creates another problem for me about configuration of qtcreator .pro file. I accept the solution. I'll ask another question.