# how to import project header files from another project and use it as library for qtcreator projects

Tags: c++, include, project, qt-creator

I have two projects in qtcreator: BiosPatcher - the code & BiosPatcherTest - googletest unit tests for BiosPatcher code. Advice from here:

[multiple main declaration in qtcreator project which uses googletest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37765182/multiple-main-declaration-in-qtcreator-project-which-uses-googletest)

How to import sources from one project in another and connect builded project as library in qtcreator to another qtcreator project?

BiosPatcher project has:

```
BiosPatcher\src\bios\Bios.{cpp, hpp} class
```

and in BiosPatcherTest i have test:

```
#include "src/bios/Bios.hpp" //not works
...
TEST(BiosTest, testReadMethodReadsFromBiosIO) {
MockBiosIO mockBiosIO;
EXPECT_CALL(mockBiosIO, readAsBytes())
    .Times(AtLeast(1));

MockReentrantLock mockReentrantLock;
MockBiosVector mockBiosVector;
MockPatch mockPatch;
MockLog mockLog;

Bios bios;
bios.setBiosIO(&mockBiosIO);
bios.setLock(&mockReentrantLock);
bios.setBiosBytesVector(&mockBiosVector);
bios.setLog(&mockLog);
bios.setPatch(&mockPatch);

bios.read();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First, you need create `BiosPatcher` C++ shared library project.
After, you need just add `BIOSPATCHER_LIBRARY` to class declaration

this

```
class BiosPatcher
{
```

need to be replaced by this

```
class BIOSPATCHERSHARED_EXPORT BiosPatcher
{
```

and after it just compile your library and include same headers in your second project, and add to linking generated `.lib` file.

```
DEPENDPATH''= . ../BiosPatcher
INCLUDEPATH ''= ../BiosPatcher
LIBS''= -L../BiosPatcher/debug -lBiosPatcher
```

When I created library project in my Qt Creator with name `BiosPatcher`, IDE automaticly created `biospatcher_global.h` file, that containts `BIOSPATCHERSHARED_EXPORT` defination. That file need to be included in all library headers.
You see, if defined `BIOSPATCHER_LIBRARY` then `BIOSPATCHERSHARED_EXPORT`  will be defined as `Q_DECL_EXPORT`, else `Q_DECL_IMPORT`. `BIOSPATCHER_LIBRARY` is defined in library `.pro` file, that means if you include those headers from another project, class will be imported from compiled library.

```
#ifndef BIOSPATCHER_GLOBAL_H
#define BIOSPATCHER_GLOBAL_H

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#if defined(BIOSPATCHER_LIBRARY)
#  define BIOSPATCHERSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define BIOSPATCHERSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif // BIOSPATCHER_GLOBAL_H
```

Also read this: https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application